# Is there an image viewer that can automatically remove metadata?

Tags: linux, images, metadata

I need an image viewer or a daemon or anything for Linux that automatically removes metadata from any image downloaded or opened.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: if by metadata you mean EXIF tags and by any image you mean an image in the format which supports EXIF tags - would http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13251/batch-delete-exif-info work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageMagick. The command line `convert` has a `-strip` flag that removes "profiles and comments". See more [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip)